# Using angularJS function in phantomJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phantomjs

I searched on the net and I found nothing.
I have a script angularJS which appear or disappear element from my html page.
I use a phantomJS script to access to the html page and do some stuffs. But Can I use the `$scope` or the functions of my angular script in my phantom script ?
I know that I can use jQuery but angular i don't know.

Comment: `$scope` is part of callbacks in angularjs (controllers and such), you don't have direct access to it, but maybe you can register a directive or something like that to get access from `page.evaluate()`.

Comment: Yes, in fast I finally found. In `page.evaluate()` we can access to jQuery like this `$('#something').action` but it's different in angular. It's like this : `angular.element($("#something")).scope()`. I put the answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found. A script PhantomJS use javascript so we just have to call angularJS element like in javascript:

This is `angular.element($("#someThing")).scope();` to get the scope.

So we can have this example of phantomJS :

```
page.open('http://www.google.com', function (status) {
    if ('success' !== status) {
        console.log("Error");
    } else {
        page.evaluate(function() {          
            angular.element($("#someThing")).scope().aFunctionInTheScope();
            var scope = angular.element($("#myDiv")).scope();
            var width = scope.getWidth();
        });
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

with an angularJS code like this :

```
$scope.getWidth = function() {
     return 1600;
}
```

and an html page like this :

```
<div id="myDiv">
    blabla
</div>
```