# Call AngularJS Function from CasperJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-directive, casperjs

I have a directive that is inside a controller. I am trying to write unit tests to test what happens when this code is executed. The code is called not from a click event or anything but from a `socket.io` emit.  Rather than trying to mock `socket.io` I'm trying to call the function directly from **casper.js** not **phantom.js**

here is the directive

```
// exposed to UI with a poniter
scope.testingText = testingText;

function testingText(int, string) {
    return int + string;
}
```

The function I have in the casper suite is:

```
function callDirectiveJavascript() {
    casper.evaluate(function () {            
        var test = scope.testingText(100, 'string');
        console.log('test:' + test);
    });
}
```

The `console.log` statement is never evaluated. When I run

```
casper.on( 'page.error', function (msg, trace) {
    this.echo( 'Error: ' + msg, 'ERROR' );
});
```

`scope` is not defined. Trying to figure out how to get access to the scope of my directive.

Any ideas? Beyond just the `console.log`, I've seen people calling `js` through `casper` with this implementation, but haven't seen it specific to `angularjs`

Comment: not a duplicate, the console.log is not within the function I'm calling

Comment: I'm looking for help with casperjs not phantomjs...

Comment: Sorry for that..I reopened it now..

Comment: @PankajParkar Please don't use you hammer when you are not sure and don't reopen immediately just because the OP doesn't immediately see the connection.

Comment: Duplicate: [Using angularJS function in phantomJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30502454/using-angularjs-function-in-phantomjs), because `casper.evaluate()` is the exact same function as `page.evaluate()`.

Comment: Not a duplicate as it mentions accessing items from the directive, see answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment that marks this as a duplicate was helpful in solving the issue, but I don't feel is an exact duplicate. It does not address accessing functions on the directive.

If in your directive scope declaration you are passing items into the directive

**part of directive declaration**

```
var directive = {
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
        denominations: '='
    },
    templateUrl: '/app/myPath.html',
    link: link
};
```

**HTML of controller that has directive embeded**

```
<div id="denominations" cr-denominations denominations="vm.denominations"></div>
```

**syntax to access directive scope is as follows**

```
angular.element(document.getElementById('elementId')).children().scope().theFunctionINeeded(dataObject);
```

If you aren't passing items into the directive. I believe you can use:

```
scope: true
```

in the directive declaration and you won't need to use the .children() notation.